# Why does SonarQube add "Not enough arguments." for log methods with message and Throwable?

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube

I am using `self4j` for putting logger

```
LOGGER.info("Exception occurred while saving data {}", be);
```

But above statement showing sonar issue `Not enough arguments.` Using sonar lint 5.3.1 in eclipse

If I update above Logger as below then its not showing any issue

```
LOGGER.info("Exception occurred while saving data", be);
```

Or if I extract logger string in any constant file then its also working fine

```
private static final String LOG_STR = "Exception occurred while saving data {}";

LOGGER.info(LOG_STR , be);
```

Why its behaving different in different scenario?

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions in this post.

### Why message with `{}` has `Not enough arguments.`?

SLF4J [Logger](http://slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html) class has a few variants for every log method:

1. [info(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)](http://slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object))
2. [info(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)](http://slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))
3. [info(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)](http://slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable))

The first and the second variants take a message and parameters which will be injected into it. The third takes a static message because exceptions are handled in a different way. I believe `be` is an exception. It means that here:

```
// issue: not enough arguments
LOGGER.info("Exception occurred while saving data {}", be);
```

You execute the third option which doesn't support `{}`. If you want to display only exception message and hide the stack trace (which will be logged by default when you use the third variant) - you should call `toString()` on `be`.

```
// okay, call info(String, String), so one parameter is available
LOGGER.info("Exception occurred while saving data {}", be.toString());
```

## Why the code with constant doesn't produce an error?

I believe there is a bug in the rule, which you should report it on [SonarSource Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/).